# Definition of a uniformly bounded dual of a group

Tags: rt.representation-theory, rigidity, lie-groups, geometric-group-theory

The unitary dual of a group $G$ is the set of equivalence classes of irreducible unitary representations of $G$ with the Fell topology. (This topology is defined using convergence of positive definite functions, or equivalently, diagonal matrix coefficients, associated to the representations).

> **Question:** How to define a "uniformly bounded dual" of $G$ using uniformly bounded representations on a Hilbert space and what topology should it be equipped with?

Such a uniformly bounded dual is mentioned a few times in the literature, but usually vaguely defined to be "analogous to the unitary dual". In particular, there is hardly any explicit statement about what topology is used.

I am interested in this since I would like to understand a series of results of M. Cowling from the early 1980s on a stronger version of Kazhdan's property (T). Cowling proved that for a simple Lie group $\Gamma$, the trivial representation is isolated in such a uniformly bounded dual if and only if the rank of $\Gamma$ is $\ge 2$.

In the case of $Sp(n,1)$ Cowling constructs an explicit family of uniformly bounded representations that approximate the trivial representation. The best description of his construction I have found is in his abstract from an Oberwolfach workshop from 2001 on the geometrization of property (T) (see [MFO report](http://www.mfo.de/document/0128a/Report_29_01.ps), the following abstract is on page 3):

[image]

Comment: Note that for unitary representations it is usually easier to describe neighborhoods of the trivial representation than of an arbitrary unitary rep (there are subtleties with convex combinations...). Here you might want to specify how you expect the operator norm to converge. If a sequence $\pi_i$ converges to the identity, and $K$ is a compact neighbourhood of 1 in the group, do you want $\sup_K\|\pi_i(g)\|$ to tend to 1? or just to be bounded? Or none?

Comment: Yves, no behavior of norms of the representations is assumed. In fact Cowling has proved that  for $Sp(n,1)$ the trivial representation can be approximated by uniformly bounded ones, even though $Sp(n,1)$ has (T). However, the norms of these uniformly bounded representations blow up to infinity as one approaches the trivial one. 

Comment: Are you allowing u.b. representations on (reflexive) Banach spaces other than Hilbert space?

Comment: Yemon, I am only considering the Hilbert space.

Comment: @Piotr: I'm confused about the meaning of your question. Could you specify a little more what you would like? can you at least define the  nets converging to the trivial representation? (Besides, the unitary dual usually means the sets of classes of *irreducible reps*,  although I agree the Fell topology is natural to define on all reps, leaving aside that they don't form a set.)

Comment: Understanding how nets converge to the trivial representation is pretty much what I am looking for. More specifically, I would like to know the meaning of the term "isolated" in the context of Cowling's results. One example of his results is that for $Sp(n,1)$ the trivial representation *is not* isolated within the uniformly bounded representations. Another is that for simple Lie groups of rank at least 2, the trivial representation *is* isolated within the uniformly bounded ones. Also, of course I meant irreducible in the definition of the unitary dual, I'll edit the question.

Comment: OK, well, I'd rather had written the question as "What is the topology considered by Cowling in...". It seems to me that the natural approach to such a question is just to ask him, if he hasn't written the definition in any of his papers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried the obvious alternate routes already, moreover, it seemed that MO is the natural place to ask such a question. Several other people also reference or use Cowling's results in their work. For instance, Julg has an approach to the Baum-Connes conjecture with coefficients for $Sp(n,1)$ and mentioned the "u.b. dual" explicitly; Shalom's unpublished proof that $Sp(n,1)$ admits a proper affine action with uniformly bounded linear part is also based on Cowling's result, as far as I know. However, the meaning of the term "isolated" is never defined precisely.

Comment: @Piotr: In Cowling's results, does the family of representations that Cowling looks at satisfy the property that $\sup_\pi \|\pi(g)\| < \infty$ for every $g \in G$?

Comment: @Mikael: in Cowling's result for $Sp(n,1)$, there is a family of representations $\{\pi_i\}$, such that $\pi_i\to 1$ and for each $i$ we have $\Vert \pi_i\Vert=\sup_{g\in G}\Vert \pi_i(g)\Vert<\infty$, but apparently $\Vert \pi_i\Vert\to \infty$ as $\pi_i\to 1$. This last fact is mentioned in a paper of Julg on the Baum-Connes conjecture in the Comptes Rendus.

Comment: @Piotr: thanks. I had a look at Julg's paper, and in the last lemma he states that the representations Cowling considers indeed satisfy $\sup_\pi \|\pi(g)\| < \infty$ for all $g$. Cowling's results therefore fit in the framework I had in mind. I'll explain this in an answer.

Comment: I don't have time right now to write more, and I don't know Cowling's work, but the way Julg uses it fits in the framework of Lafforgue's (T) renforcée. One can therefore see Lafforgue's theorem that hyperbolic group do not have (T) renforcée as a generalization of Cowling's work. I can expand on this later if you have questions.

Comment: @Mikael: I agree that Lafforgue's strong (T) generalizes this in some sense, but he is considering representations which are not necessarily uniformly bounded, but satisfy some growth conditions. Thus the fact you mention for hyperbolic groups should be, at least philosophically, weaker than what Cowling proved for $Sp(n,1)$ (provided the two properties are directly comparable).